# What is the difference between RemoteWebDriver and WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I actually couldn't find a good explanation of whats the difference between RemoteWebDriver and a WebDriver in Selenium.

Here's a code where eclipse told me to cast WebDriver to RemoteWebDriver.

```java
(!((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId().toString().contains("null"))
```

So why shouldn't I just use RemoteWebDriver instead of WebDriver?

Comment: remote is for running the driver using browsers on other machines.

Comment: Check Java docs https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html and https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/. e.g. Search Context Interface -> Webdriver Interface  -> RemoteWebdriver Class -> Chromium driver Class -> Chrome driver Class

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`RemoteWebDriver` is a concrete class that implements interface `WebDriver`.

`RemoteWebDriver` class contains additional methods that are not declared by interface `WebDriver`. The method `'getSessionId()'` is one of them.

Hence, your object needed to be explicitly downcasted to use `getSessionId` method since `WebDriver` itself does not have knowledge of any method or variable which is purely defined by `RemoteWebDriver`.

> Coming to the question - "why shouldn't I just use `RemoteWebDriver` instead of `WebDriver`?"

Yes you may use `RemoteWebDriver` instead of `WebDriver`, however it makes the code non-compliant with the design principle - `'Code to the interface'`

Your code will work fine though without any issues.

However, it will not have flexibility to use other driver implementations that may come in future (though very unlikely) which implements `WebDriver` but does not extend `RemoteWebdriver`. In such case, a variable of type `RemoteWebDriver` cannot be assigned to an object of the class is which `WebDriver's` implementation but not extending `RemoteWebDriver`