# What's the difference between WebDriver and RemoteWebDriver in selenium? When and where we use them?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I haven't got a clear explanation of these two. Can anyone please explain this to me?

1. What's WebDriver and RemoteWebDriver? When and where we can declare it in selenium scripts?
2. In place of WebDriver can we declare the RemoteWebDriver?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between RemoteWebDriver and WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528987/what-is-the-difference-between-remotewebdriver-and-webdriver)

Comment: Here are some more related [questions and answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium+remotewebdriver+vs.+webdriver+site:stackoverflow.com) which may help, for more background.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that RemoteWebDriver is to run selenium on other machines.

RemoteWebDriver as interface of WebDriver and few more methods.

on your local machine you can use both RemoteWebDriver & WebDriver but if you will to run it on different machine, you will need to use RemoteWebDriver.